# Change style based on property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

On a `Canvas` of the main window I'm drawing some sensors.

I created the class "Sensor"

```cs
public class Sensor
{
    public int Id_Sens { get; set; }    
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public UIElement Ui_Element { get; set; }
}
```

Programmatically I create a `Grid` with two columns (a `Rectangle` with the same WIDTH and HEIGHT (-> become a square), with  the following Style, in the first one and a `Label` in the second). I associate this `Grid` with the `Ui_Element` (`Ui_Element`  = `gridMain`).

This works fine.

Based on the value of the property `Type`, I want to change the radius of the `Rectangle` (and draw a circle)

I created the follow XAML

```xml
<Style x:Key="Sens_Shape" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="60"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="60"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How do I bind the property `Type` of the class `Sensor` to the trigger?

EDIT
I solved with the points 1 and 3 of of EldHasp

Comment: The code you have appears correct for binding the property to the `DataTrigger`. But a rectangle isn't a circle, so it's not clear why you intend to happen by setting the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` values, on an object that doesn't have those properties. Please improve your question by providing a proper [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: I forgot to tell that the Rectangle have the same Width and Height (so it is a Square)

If I set RadiusX = 60 e RadiusY = 60 it become a circle

In my WPF works the drawing of the circle if i force the values. The problem is the binding

Comment: Bindings are created to the properties of the Data Context.
But form to your explanations, it is not clear how you create UI elements, layuot them, what their Data Context is, how it is related to the original Sensor's collection.
Add details to the explanation of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not give an exact answer, because there are not enough details in the original question.

1. The element that you show in the Window is recorded in the property `public UIElement Ui_Element`?
   If so, then change the property type to `public FrameworkElement Ui_Element`, since the Style and DataContext properties are defined on the FrameworkElement, not UIElement.
2. If it is a narrower type (for example, it is always Shape as in your examples), then it is even better to specify this narrower type.
3. If the style shown by you is the style of the element in the Ui_Element property, then it is enough to pass the Sensor into the Data Context of this element.
   Example: `sensor.Ui_Element.DataContext = sensor;`.
4. You are very vainly creating UI elements on Sharpe.
   The core language of WPF is XAML. And in very rare, rather difficult cases, it is worth using Sharp instead.
   In most cases, a XAML solution will be more simpler, more typical, more understandable than Sharpe.
   In your case, you should create a Sensor's collection without the Ui_Element property.
   Create a template selector for the Sensor which, by the Type property, will set its visual appearance.
   In XAML, set the ItemsControl for this collection and give it a template selector.
   Besides there are several other typical WPF implementations.